# Python Rainfall program TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, arrays

So I am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/", line 8, in 
    total = total+x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
array = []
total = 0
max = 0
min = 0
for i in range(12):
    x= input("Enter rainfall for each of the 12 months:")
array.append(x)
total = total+x
if array[max]< x:
    max = i
if array[min] > x:
    min = i
print("The total rainfall in the year is ", total)
print("The average rainfall for the year is ", total / 12.0)
print("Month number ", max + 1, " has the highest rainfall which is ", array[max])
print("Month number ", min + 1, " has the lowest rainfall which is ", array[min])
```

Comment: input() always gives you string. So you want to do: total += int(x)

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` from input is `str` not `int`. Just convert it to `int` before using it:

```
x= input("Enter rainfall for each of the 12 months:")
x = int(x)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused were you referring to the line x= input("Enter rainfall for each of the 12 months:") and to instead make it x= int(input("Enter rainfall for each of the 12 months:")) ?

Comment: @user10784270 yes